# Forcing user input after making selection

Tags: excel, validation, cell

I have a questionnaire in Excel and I am required to force the user to include a comment if they answer 'No' to a question from a drop down box. How is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: you could make a user form that prompts them to input the value in the form then inserts it in the correct cell. I would include the yes/no question in that same form for simplicity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was commented, you should probably use [this Macro](http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/vba-inputbox/)
 in order to prompt the user for input if he clicks on it.

Then, consider [this page](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/445128-visual-basic-applications-force-user-fill-cell-use-required-click-button.html) for forcing the user to click the required button. With a bit of tweaking you should be able to force an input after he answers "No" on a different cell.

Comment: Thank you, this has been very helpful. Much appreciated

Comment: I'm happy it helped! If it answered your question please let us know by marking the answer as "accepted". If not, feel free to provide more information on what is not working so, preferably with details on your attempt thus far